# How to iterate thru a dataframe sending batches of 1000 records at a time until it reaches the total 30K records

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator, batching

I have a 30K records dataframe, and I am passing it through an API call to get data validation. To call all 30K at once would crush the Python kernel; is there a way to have a for loop that loops through my entire dataframe 1000 records at a time?

This is how I am pulling 1000 records:

```
df1, errors = extract_data(df=data1, limit=1000, timeout=60)
df1
```

`extract_data` is a function where I can limit the records I send to my API call, in this case limiting it to 1K.

But I want something like this:

```
LIMIT = 1000
for index in data1.iterrows():
    df1, errors = extract_data(df=data1, limit=1000, timeout=60)
    if LIMIT == index, break
```

Answer (score 1):

[iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) is your friend:

```py
for index in range(0, 30):
    df.iloc[index * 1000: (index + 1) * 1000]
```

Comment: Thanks @Cor - but how can I pass the 'df1, errors = extract_data(df=data1, limit=1000, timeout=60)' in the for loop?

Comment: Does `extract_data(df=df.iloc[index * 1000: (index + 1) * 1000], limit=1000, timeout=60)` work?